# How to split text using a list of keywords

Tags: python, split

I am trying split my data so that I can categorize/classify. Below sample data, although is most are well labelled, but all is written in one string under description.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":['Kelly', 'David', 'Mandy', "John"], "description":["age: 12 gender:female hobbies: loves to read", "age:16, gender:male, hobbies: play soccer", "age: 15, gender:female, hobbies: cooking","18, male, reading"]})



df
```

|  | name | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Kelly | age: 12 gender:female hobbies: loves to read |
| 1 | David | age:16, gender:male, hobbies: play soccer |
| 2 | Mandy | age: 15, gender:female, hobbies: cooking |
| 3 | John | 18, male, reading |

I decided to focus on the descriptions that has label first since they are already well labelled. However, if I split by ":", it won't show the desired outcome I wanted. I tried using re.findall() function and although it gives me the key labels, I still not sure how to split my data according to the key labels found. Below is what I hope to achieve first.

|  | name | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Kelly | age: 12 |
| 1 | Kelly | gender:female |
| 2 | Kelly | hobbies: loves to read |
| 3 | David | age:16 |
| 4 | David | gender:male |
| 5 | David | hobbies: play soccer |
| 6 | Mandy | age: 15 |
| 7 | Mandy | gender:female |
| 8 | Mandy | hobbies: cooking |
| 9 | John | 18, male, reading |

Comment: @NuriTaş hi, there is no commas in the description for Kelly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using regular expressions to help search and parse the strings, like below:

```
# Import statements
import pandas as pd
import re

# Your initial data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":['Kelly', 'David', 'Mandy', "John"], "description":["age: 12 gender:female hobbies: loves to read", "age:16, gender:male, hobbies: play soccer", "age: 15, gender:female, hobbies: cooking","18, male, reading"]})

# set regex values to search for in your data frame
ageRegex = '(age)?' + '\s?' + ':?' +  '\s?' + '[0-9][0-9]?'
genderRegex = '(gender)?' + '\s?' + ':?' +  '\s?'+ '(fe)?' + 'male'

# create dictionary to store some output
dictOutput = {}

# for each index in our data frame
for index in df.index:
    #create a dictionary of values for each name
    dictBuilder = {}
    nameValue = df.loc[index,'name']
    description_startValue = df.loc[index,'description'].replace(",","")
    #Try to get our age value
    age = re.search(ageRegex, description_startValue).group(0)
    #Try to get our gender value
    gender = re.search(genderRegex, description_startValue).group(0)
    #Per the sample data, the remaining text should be the hobby value
    hobbyValue = description_startValue.split(gender)[1]
    
    #set those values to the working dictionary created above
    dictBuilder["age"] = age
    dictBuilder["gender"] = gender
    dictBuilder["hobbies"] = hobbyValue

    #Set our working dictionary to the output dictionary created outside the loop
    dictOutput[nameValue] = dictBuilder

#parse our dictionary to create a list of values to use in a data frame
listBuilder = []
for eachDictionary in dictOutput:
    nameVal = eachDictionary
    for eachValue in dictOutput[eachDictionary]:
        listBuilder.append([nameVal, dictOutput[eachDictionary][eachValue]])

#create a new data frame with our list of values
df2 = pd.DataFrame(listBuilder, columns=("Name", "Description"))

#debug print statement
print(df2)
```

That should yield an output like below:

```
     Name              Description
0   Kelly                  age: 12
1   Kelly            gender:female
2   Kelly   hobbies: loves to read
3   David                   age:16
4   David              gender:male
5   David     hobbies: play soccer
6   Mandy                  age: 15
7   Mandy            gender:female
8   Mandy         hobbies: cooking
9    John                       18
10   John                     male
11   John                  reading
```

You could consider enhancing the Regex searching to further clean your input, so each value like age, gender, and hobbies would be formatted with the same prefix (*some type of find and replace*)

Below is a thread on regex functions that may help a bit

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp